# Fake user ON by default in Blender materials and textures

Tags: python, materials, add-on, customization

How can I set the F button for materials and textures to be always on, even when I create a new material?

I don't know Python and I don't have time to learn it, but I have found that there is a property `use_fake_user` that must be set `True` for materials.

The reason for asking is that I sometimes loose my unassigned materials when I play with multiple objects and multiple material nodes created on the fly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an app handler to set `use_fake_user` to `True` right before saving. The following addon does it for materials and textures:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Save unused Materials and Textures",
    "author": "CoDEmanX",
    "version": (1, 0, 0),
    "blender": (2, 63, 0),
    "location": "(none)",
    "description": "Enable fake user to rescue unused materials / textures automatically before saving",
    "warning": "Make sure this addon is enabled by default!",
    "category": "Material"}


import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent
from itertools import chain

@persistent
def enable_fakeuser(scene):
    for datablock in chain(bpy.data.materials, bpy.data.textures):
        datablock.use_fake_user = True


def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.save_pre.append(enable_fakeuser)


def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.save_pre.remove(enable_fakeuser)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Make sure this addon is really enabled (best make it enabled by default and do that whenever you update Blender).

Comment: Yes! I'd buy you a beer if you were in Bucharest :)