# How to stop blender from purging unused materials when closing

Tags: materials, properties, settings

Where can I change the setting that makes blender purge unused materials when closing your project?

I lost several materials just because they were not in use at the moment I saved and closed blender.
This off course is not desirable and blender should not remove anything from the blend file without asking....

Assigning a mesh to every material in the project is not a solution because this makes the blend file unnecessary big....

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have many unused materials, you can also assign them a *'fake user'* in the outliner.

In the Outliner, use the Orphan Data View, then in Materials, select what you want and either click on their 'shield' icons (on the right of the image below) or right click the material and choose 'Add fake user'.

[image]

Comment: Note that there is an add-on  that can supposedly do this automatically for materials and textures.  See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9294/42221) for the code.  I haven't tested it though.

Answer (score 6):

Press on the shield icon in order to make sure that your material (or any other data) is safe. The name of the material will then be preceded by the letter "F" like "Fake User". As long as the name is preceded by "0" it means that the data has no user and that it will be lost when you'll close the file:

[image]

Comment: Also, go on Rightclick select community and upvote all the feature requests about making data persistent by default. That's a long term solution. :D

Comment: maybe the whole data management should be revised

Comment: That's the point of mots of these requests. Why even delete data without the user's request in the first place? Sure you can prevent it once you know about it, but that's still a surprising discovery to do, highly unusual and easy to forget. Especially when you create data in Blender.

Comment: @moonboots Thanks that worked.....

Now I can recreate the materials I lost (if I remember the steps LOL) and assign them a fake user.

Comment: @L0Lock, I don't even pay attention anymore but at the beginning this is disturbing for sure

Comment: FWIW, Blender is only doing what every programming language with _garbage collection_, such as Python, does: pruning unused data.  The other side of the coin is why should I have to take an extra step to delete something I'm not using any more?

Comment: @MartyFouts IMO there is no need to remove data automatically - why should saving the file and then re-opening it be a trigger for removing "unused" blocks...? Perhaps have an option to specifically do it (in which case, list to the user what will be removed and let them authorise it) - to save space in the project, but it is quite inexcusable to simply remove something just on the basis that it isn't used *at the moment the file was saved*.

Comment: I accept that garbage collection is exactly this, but that's a completely different situation of removing resources that are not in use and will never be in use (due to being effectively "unlinked" from any active data structure), compared to removing resources, etc. that have been specifically created and may be intended to be used by the user in future.

Comment: @RichSedman I was only explaining the motivation, not justifying the design choices.  Where your opinion differs from the devs is that they seem to think all data blocks should get the same treatment, so they apply the same rules to deleted meshes as they do to materials no longer in use.  Once they've chosen consistency, the file close time is the least harmful of the available choices for reaping unlinked data.  They could reap as soon as use count goes to 0 after all, giving you no chance to recover.

Comment: @MartyFouts Yeah - I can be a bit of a pain. It has caught me out quite a few times - you quickly learn to always click the ‘fake user’ button. Perhaps we need an add-on to automatically ‘fake user’ everything :-D

Comment: @RichSedman  I assume you mean _It_ can be a bit of a pain.  I certainly don't think _you_ are ;).  If you're serious about the add-on I could look into creating it. It shouldn't be hard, just a hook to enable fake user when a data block is created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131409/discussion-between-marty-fouts-and-rich-sedman).

Comment: Haha! Yes, *it* rather than *I*. That’s what I get tot typing on a fiddly phone screen and not reading it back properly :-D